# Python shows same results for every page. Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, while-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm super new to Python and I am trying to scrape some stuff from google scholar as a project. The code with the problem looks like this:

```
    yearList = []
def getYear():
    for div in soup.find_all("div", class_='gs_a'):
        yearRegex = re.compile(r".*(\d\d\d\d).*")
        yo = yearRegex.findall(div.text)
        yearList.append(yo)
    print(yearList)



page = 0
i = 0 
while i < numPages:

    link = 'https://scholar.google.de/scholar?start=' + str(page) + '&q=' + search + '&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5'
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    getYear()    #this is the function that extracts the data
    page += 20      #to get to the next page of the results
    i += 1`
```

The page variable and the link actually change by 20 each time. However, for some reason the program just scrapes the first page of the search results, as if the link variable had never changed. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you examined what is inside the `soup`? Do you see the "Sorry..." page title? If yes, then it's that the website detects you are sending automated requests and bans your IP.

Comment: check the value of numPages and also verify how many times the while loop runs

Comment: @Shijo : numPages is working fine, and the loop runs exactly as many times as I want it to. if I put in 3 it runs exactly 3 times and gives me 3 times the same results

Comment: @alecxe No it doesnt ban me, it parses the same page 3 times though.

Comment: @Jannik what is `getAll()` doing and why `soup` is not passed into it?

Comment: It is possible that Google uses Javascript for pagination. `requests` cannot handle that. I would try to use Selenium with Phantomjs.

Comment: @alecxe its using Regex to extract the data I want. Also soup is in it, I just coded it a bit weirdly.

Comment: @Mikk thanks I will try to do that

Comment: @Mikk I just checked again. And the response actually changes for each page. So request ist actually able to call the second page of the search results. So that was not the problem

Comment: I added the code to the question it's easier to read there @alecxe